# How to convert a String into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, converters

In my String, I can have an arbitrary number of words which are comma separated. I wanted each word added into an ArrayList. E.g.:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e,.........";
```

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Try something like

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

- [`Arrays.asList` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)
- [`String.split` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`ArrayList(Collection)` constructor documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

---

Demo:

```
String s = "lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet";

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));

System.out.println(myList);  // prints [lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet]
```

---

This post has been rewritten as an article [here](http://programming.guide/java/split-string-into-arraylist.html).

Comment: +1: The `new ArrayList<String>()` may be redundant depending on how it is used. (as it is in your example ;)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, +1 :-) It may actually even just be the `split` his after :P

Comment: He would have to use `Arrays.toString()` to print it, but yes.

Comment: The new ArrayList<String>() causes a new list to be created with the returned list inside of it. Arrays.asList(a) returns a List object thus don't call new ArrayList you will get unwanted behavior.

Comment: Note that you can't add elements to the list returned by Arrays.asList. The OP wanted to have an ArrayList (which is completely reasonable) and the the ArrayList construction *is* necessary.

Comment: is that posibble to convert string to byte with this method?

Comment: @mehmet, no. Use `String.getBytes`.

Comment: `List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(S.split("")).stream()
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()); `

Comment: @AlejandroHernandez.Inc splitting `S` on `""`, wrapping it in a `List` and calling `.stream()` is basically a long way of doing `S.chars()`. Then there's a actually a method available specifically to go from chars such as `'6'` to integers `6`: [`Character::getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-) so I would rather express your snippet as follows: `S.chars().mapToObj(Character::getNumericValue).collect(Collectors.toList())` or, if you're on Java 16+, simply `.toList()` in the end.

Answer (score 36):

```
 String s1="[a,b,c,d]";
 String replace = s1.replace("[","");
 System.out.println(replace);
 String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
 System.out.println(replace1);
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
 System.out.println(myList.toString());
```

Comment: If you have to trim brackets, you could do it in one step with `replace = s1.replaceAll("^\\[|]$", "");`

Comment: I used this answer, but my user sometimes uses `","` and others `", "` as separators, so I added a `.replaceAll(", ", ",")` before `split` function.

Answer (score 17):

In Java 9, using [**`List#of`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable), which is an Immutable List Static Factory Methods, become more simpler.

```
 String s = "a,b,c,d,e,.........";
 List<String> lst = List.of(s.split(","));
```

Comment: `s.split("\\s*,\\s*")` can be added for extra care

Answer (score 14):

**Option1**:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello");
```

**Option2**:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("hello"));
```

In my opinion, Option1 is better because

1. we can reduce the number of ArrayList objects being created from 2 to 1. `asList` method creates and returns an ArrayList Object.
2. its performance is much better (but it returns a fixed-size list).

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Comment: Why doesn't this work       

```List<Character> word1 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(A[0].toCharArray()));```
I'm trying to get first String of an string array, and convert that string into charArray and that charArray to List<Character>

Comment: that's because, asList method in Arrays class takes only Object array, not primitive arrays. If you convert char[] to Character[] array it will work.

Comment: public static Character[] boxToCharacter(char[] charArray) {
 Character[] newArray = new Character[charArray.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (char value : charArray) {
        newArray[i++] = Character.valueOf(value);
    }
    return newArray;
}

Answer (score 7):

Easier to understand is like this:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e";
String[] sArr = s.split(",");
List<String> sList = Arrays.asList(sArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok i'm going to extend on the answers here since a lot of the people who come here want to split the string by a **whitespace**. This is how it's done:

```
List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are importing or you have an array (of type string) in your code and you have to convert it into arraylist (offcourse string) then use of collections is better. like this:

```
String array1[] = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("key1"); or String array1[] = ... then

List allEds = new ArrayList(); Collections.addAll(allEds, array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You should ask yourself if you really need the ArrayList in the first place. Very often, you're going to filter the list based on additional criteria, for which a Stream is perfect. You may want a set; you may want to filter them by means of another regular expression, etc. Java 8 provides this very useful extension, by the way, which will  work on any `CharSequence`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-. Since you don't need the array at all, avoid creating it thus:

```
// This will presumably be a static final field somewhere.
Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
// ...
String untokenized = reader.readLine();
Stream<String> tokens = splitter.splitAsStream(untokenized);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a **string** into a **ArrayList** try this:

```
public ArrayList<Character> convertStringToArraylist(String str) {
    ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();      
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){
        charList.add(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return charList;
}
```

But i see a string array in your example, so if you wanted to convert a **string array** into **ArrayList** use this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> convertStringArrayToArraylist(String[] strArr){
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : strArr) {
        stringList.add(s);
    }
    return stringList;
}
```

Comment: A simpler character based approach would be:                           ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Character c :s.toCharArray() ) {
 myList.add(c.toString());
} But I don't think this is what the person is looking for. The solution by aioobe is what is required. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a question : Reverse a String. I shall do this using stream().collect(). But first I shall change the string into an ArrayList .

```
    public class StringReverse1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Gini Gina  Proti";

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split("")));

        list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection( LinkedList :: new ))
        .descendingIterator()
        .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);



    }}
/*
The output :
i
t
o
r
P


a
n
i
G

i
n
i
G
*/
```

Comment: so... you are using the accepted solution to make an example about a different problem? why?

Answer (score 1):

This is using Gson in Kotlin

```
 val listString = "[uno,dos,tres,cuatro,cinco]"
 val gson = Gson()
 val lista = gson.fromJson(listString , Array<String>::class.java).toList()
 Log.e("GSON", lista[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use the StringTokenizer, is very efficient

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

     StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(value, LIST_SEPARATOR);
     while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
           list.add(token.nextToken());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using guava (and you should be, see [effective java item #15](https://www.google.com/search?q=effective%20java%20immutable)):

```
ImmutableList<String> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(s.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "java spring springboot microservices";

ArrayList<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value.split(" "));
```

Comment: You need to explain your code, so beginners reading it will have an easy time understanding it. An answer should consist educatory information, which is even more important than the solution itself.