# STRING to ArrayList<String> using TypeReference

Tags: java, arraylist

```
str = "[tdr1w6v, tdr1w77]";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().
                constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, String.class);
ArrayList<String> list = null;
        try {
            list = objectMapper.readValue(str,
                    new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here an exception is thrown :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'tdr1w6v': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
```

How can I convert str to ArrayList of string ?

Comment: It seems that this is not proper JSON. Where do you get it from? Try with `"[\"tdr1w6v\", \"tdr1w77\"]";`.

Comment: Actually I mapped JSONArray to ArrayList<String> and dumped the `ArrayList<String>.toString` to db.

Comment: Convert `JSONArray` to string representing valid JSON structure if you want to retrieve it back using JSON parser. From which package `JSONArray` comes from?

Comment: `{"path": [
    "tdr1w6v",
    "tdr1w77"
    ]}`
Map it to `ArrayList<String> path`. Then use the model class to create a DAO and push data to data base. In the mapper for DAO implementation, I convert it to `path.toString()`. That is the format in which this method saves in db.

Comment: You can probably get the answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347856/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-arraylist

Comment: That I have already implemented @pmartin8 . Looking for a better solution :)

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Faster? Simpler?

Comment: Meaning, I can set the property for ObjectMapper at one configuration class. And will not have to split string, instead inject ObjectMapper for both  model for service layer and DTO.

Comment: You cannot deserialize a non-json string with Jackson. Don't dump it using `path.toString()`. Dump it using anyone of `ObjectMapper`'s `write` methods.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it seems like you are suggesting the right answer. Could you please share a sample code as to how to use TypeReference while writing the value?

Comment: Thanks @pmartin8. It was a solution to the problem I mentioned. However, I needed a solution as explained by me in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement can be easily met without using TypeReference

```
String str="[tdr1w6v, tdr1w77]";
List<String> al=Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split(","));
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is same as suggested by @pmartin8.

Answer (score 3):

@FedericoPeraltaSchaffner suggestion helped. Now what I do is, in my binder class use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString` to convert data to store in database. And in my Mapper class while reading from data base I can use the same way as in the question:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayList<String> list = null;
try {
        list =objectMapper.readValue(str, new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So now I don't have to create a separate DTO class, I can use the same model at service layer and DAO.