# Convert String to ArrayList<Character>, without Regex

Tags: java

Is there anyway to convert a `String` to an `ArrayList<Character>` without using regex.

For example:

```
"abc".methodHere == ArrayList<Character>["a", "b", "c"]
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347856/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-arraylist) converts a `String` to an `ArrayList<String>` and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings) uses `Array` and not `ArrayList`

Comment: Can you go from Array to ArrayList? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the characters in the string by index

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   chars.add(str.charAt(i));
// do whatever with the chars list
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the stream of characters and collect to a list:

```
List<Character> chars = s.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want an `ArrayList` specifically, you could collect to an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Character> chars = s.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

A different answer from the ones already provided:

```
ArrayList<Character> list = (ArrayList<Character>)"abc".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do

```
ArrayList<Character> chars =
     new ArrayList<>(Chars.asList(string.toCharArray()));
```

You need to `import com.google.common.primitives.Chars;` from Guava library.