# Splitting a string into a list in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string into a list base on `:,"{[ }]`
This is my code,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split("{ | } | \\"| : | [ | ]|,")));
```

Which isn't compiling. I'm not really adept at regex. Any help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String into an ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347856/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-arraylist)

Comment: Are you trying to split a json string?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I can convert the string if the delimiter is just 1 comma, but not in this case, thus the question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte kind of yes and no, it was json which I've transformed into a Java string now.

Comment: Please provide the input you are splitting

Comment: @Jérôme that's a little difficult as it has enterprise data in it. But I've worded the question correctly.

Comment: Are you going to split string by either of `:,"{[ }]`? Please provide the input and expected output:-)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you want it split "whenever you see : or , or " or { or [ or } or ]"? If so, you really don't need to say much more than:

```
.split("[:,\"{\\[ }\\]]")
```

I.e. "split on any character in the following character class definition: `:,"{[ }]`", where we use the standard regexp character class definition syntax (`[...]`) with appropriate escaping.

Normally this means a regex that looks like `/[:,"{\[ }\]]/` but because you're writing a regex *inside* of a normal string, more escapes are needed: `"` needs regular string escaping so your string doesn't end prematurely (so that becomes `\"`), and `[` and `]` are active characters in the regexp, so they need `\` before them *in the regex*. However, we can't just put `\` in the string and have it work because `\` is the escape character, so we need to "escape the escape" which means using `\\` (giving `\\[` and `\\]`).

```
String[] result = "a:b,c\"d{e[f g}h]i".split("[:,\"{\\[ }\\]]");
System.out.print(result.length);
// => result has 9 elements in it, ['a',...,'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not compiling because you didn't escape the quotation mark, but the backslash itself.

Change:

```
\\"
```

To:

```
\"
```